# Tips for hair loss problem in HeartLake world?

Tags: friends

Is there anything to do to prevent the rubber hairs (or hats) from leaving Stephanie's head?

In my opinion, hairs and head stuffs for Friends don't stay in place as well as they do in the minifig's world.

My daughter is fed up with those girls with hair loss problems!

Any tips?!

Comment: Oof. The title sounds like you're trying to solve _my_ hair loss problem. Is that intentional?

Comment: no Jan ! if I was talking about you, I would have set the 'Jan' tag, not 'friends' ! :)

Comment: Here I was, poised flag as spam...  but NOOOOOoooo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My LEGO Friends minifigs are just fine. Their hair doesn't come off that easy. Perhaps there is some difference in the mould and you ended up with some loose ones? It happends to regular minifigs too where the hair/helmet fits very loose or very tight. You could put a little bit of tacky-glue (blu-tack) inside the hair pieces to keep them on while still being able to remove/change them.

Also, I have to ask; are these minifigs directly from LEGO? There has been some sellers on eBay selling knock-off Friends minifigs from China. At first glance they look just like the real thing, but they are of lesser quality.

Comment: None of the hair pieces for any of my authentic Friends set stay on during play.